# Kernel level IP configuration not working in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

I have enabled kernel level IP configuration in my linux kernel and compiled it, but it does not try get any DHCP address. Why?

Is there something extra or special I have to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure:

- the kernel has loaded the drivers for your NIC
- DHCP is enabled for IP autoconfiguration

Then add **ip=dhcp** to the kernel command line and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

From KConfig

CONFIG_IP_PNP:

This enables automatic configuration of IP addresses of devices and
   of the routing table during kernel boot, based on either information
   supplied on the kernel command line or by BOOTP or RARP protocols.

<strike>So it can't be used with plain DHCP</strike>
For using with DHCP you need additional option.

Comment: Does you turn on CONFIG_IP_PNP_DHCP ?

Comment: config IP_PNP_DHCP
        bool "IP: DHCP support"
        depends on IP_PNP

http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.19/net/ipv4/Kconfig

Comment: Also, you need to check kernel logs: KERN_NOTICE level for "Sending ... requests" where ... can be DHCP, BOOTP, RARP